# Scanf to accept the number just before EOF (not being separated with a white space)

Tags: c

I need scanf to read numbers, including the number which is entered just before EOF (no space or enter after putting this number, just EOF - like "1 2 3 4EOF" - 4 is not read). My code looks like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
    if ((scanf ("%d", &number) != 1 && !feof(stdin)))
    {
        printf ("Wrong input.\n");
    return (0);
    }

    if (feof(stdin) && count == 0)  
    {
    printf("Empty input.\n");
    return 0;
    }

    if (feof(stdin)) break;

    field[i] = number;
    count++;
    }
```

Where is the part which needs to be adjusted to accept also the last entered number not separated before EOF? Thanks a lot, I really can't see it..

Answer (score 1):

It is the `if (feof(stdin)) break;` that does the damage. You should only break on EOF if you do not get `1` from `scanf()`.  In your example, the system knows it has reached EOF, but it also successfully converted a value, and it told you so by returning `1` from `scanf()`, but you went ahead and ignored the successfully converted value because EOF was also detected.

You should probably use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int field[100];
    int count = 0;
    int n;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int number;
        if ((n = scanf("%d", &number)) != 1)
            break;
        printf("-- %d: %d (%d)\n", i, number, n);
        field[i] = number;
        count++;
    }

    if (n == 0)
    {
        printf("Wrong input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (ferror(stdin))
    {
        printf("I/O error on stdin\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (feof(stdin) && count == 0)
    {
        printf("Empty input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Count: %d\n", count);
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        printf("%d: %d\n", j, field[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this exhibits the same issue if you enter `1 2 3 4EOF` (`1 2 3 4^D`) on input. The input buffering of C seems to "swallow" the EOF immediately after the `4` as a delimiter. At least when `scanf` is used.

Comment: +1 for a good answer and `if(ferror(stdin))`.  The `feof(stdin) && ` is not needed though.

Comment: @mbratch: I tested both with a file created by `echo -n 1 2 3 4 > data` which did not have a newline at the end of the file, and also by typing at my terminal (you have to type control-D twice, once to send the '1 2 3 4' string to the program, once to send nothing to the program, which indicates EOF).  Both times, I got the output I'd expect: `-- 0: 1 (1)
-- 1: 2 (1)
-- 2: 3 (1)
-- 3: 4 (1)
Count: 4
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4`.

Comment: @chux: now I made the conditions into an `if / else if` chain, I believe you're correct.  They were 3 separate `if` statements for a while (30 seconds, maybe); I didn't notice the optimization at the time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah OK. What I did is just run it from the command line and I typed in `1 2 3 4^D`. That somehow behaves different than a file with no newline at the end. But the OP wasn't clear about whether it was a file. Perhaps the case I ran is a bit anomalous.

Answer (score 0):

check !feof(stdin) right at the end of the loop. It will be true after you have read the last value, so in this case the last value is not stored

Comment: When I do that the last number is repeated twice as it's remembered and with the last loop taken again because !feof(stdin) is after field[i] = number.

Answer (score 0):

After successfully reading the last number via `scanf ("%d"...`,  calling `feof()` may return true *or* false, depending on if additional white space, like `\n` follows the number.  Thus `feof()` is not a definitive test to stop looping.  Simpler code is possible.

In general, avoid using `fscanf()` and `feof()` in the same parsing routine.  Instead use the return value from `fscanf()` to know when EOF occurred.

```
 while ((retval = fscanf(...)) == expected value) {
   // The happy path
   do_stuff();
 }
 if (retval == EOF) {
   Deal_with_EOF_or_IOerror();
 }
 else {
   Deal_with_unexpected_number_of_parameters_scanned();
 }
```